# Enviar video por HDMI a un monitor en C#

Tags: c#, video

Quiero desarrollar código para enviar tramas de video mediante el puerto *HDMI* de mi portátil a un monitor externo, por *C#*.

Por lo que he visto, es posible que ello se realice con algún tipo de driver *API* específico de mi tarjeta de video (*Intel HD Graphics 520*).

Lo único que quiero hacer es enviar video desde mi portátil al monitor externo, y que este lo muestre.

¿Es posible hacer esto?

Comment: creo que no se le entiende muy bien a tu pregunta

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78)

Comment: No creo que lo que quieres sea posible la verdad. La unica opcion que veo es que configures windows para que de salida al hdmi y al monitor, y en ese caso si podrías por ejemplo colocar un formulario en este escritorio extendido.

Comment: Voy a intentar explicarlo mejor,

La intención final trata de probar un dispositivo que utiliza unas tarjetas de video AverMedia, la cual tengo su SDK para C# y lo usaría para capturar video por el puerto HDMI del dispositivo.

Lo malo es que aún no me ha llegado la tarjeta en cuestión, por lo tanto, para adelantar, me gustaría empezar a desarrollar la otra parte del sistema, que será la CPU mandando tramas de video por HDMI (para que el dispositivo las recoja)

Se me ocurrió tratar de probar si primero lo recibía un monitor normal, para luego trabajar con la tarjeta.

Comment: Te repito lo mismo, no creo que sea posible. Cuando tengas el dispositivo mencionado será diferente, ya que el driver de ese dispositivo se encargará probablemente de gestionar lo que envies mediante dicho driver.

Comment: Gracias Pikoh, por la respuesta, me lo imaginaba.

Pero sigo teniendo la duda entonces, de como envío las tramas de video por HDMI (al margen de que sea al monitor o a la tarjeta para que los reciba), necesitaría unos drivers específicos para el HDMI?

Muchas gracias

Comment: El problema no es el HDMI. Cuando tengas el dispositivo, tu no te comunicarás con el hdmi, lo harás con el driver del dispositivo mediante su SDK. Los detalles quedarán a mas bajo nivel.

Comment: El término "captuar" video normalmente se refiere a mandar video de un dispositivo externo a la computadora para almacenarlo y/o procesarlo, ¿es esto lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: me gustaria saber si lograste enviar esas tramas de video, lo que yo quiero es enviar algunos datos o bits atraves del cable hdmi para "utilizarlo" como toma de corriente, como si fuese un arduino, no se si podrias ayudarme